# Azure storage account fail over

Tags: azure, azure-storage, high-availability, disaster-recovery

Following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-initiate-account-failover?tabs=azure-portal) for Azure storage fail over process all this link says about manual way of initiating the fail over process.

Is there way to do this failover process programmatically? without any manual intervention.

What is the clue or exception to trigger the fail over process?

Will Azure storage SDK raise any particular exception, in case of storage account unavailability?

How to replicate/simulate storage account unavailability to do development & testing?

Answer (score 0):

You can automate Azure Account failover with REST, Powershell or AZ CLI.

**Powershell:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-initiate-account-failover?tabs=azure-powershell#tabpanel_CeZOj-G++Q_azure-powershell

**AZ CLI:**

```
az storage account show \ --name accountName \ --expand geoReplicationStats
az storage account failover \ --name accountName
```

**REST:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storageaccounts/failover

Comment: What is the clue or exception to trigger the fail over process? Will Azure storage SDK raise any particular exception, in case of storage account unavailability? How to replicate/simulate storage account unavailability to do development & testing?

Comment: First you need to design you application to support failover
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-create-geo-redundant-storage?tabs=dotnet#retry-event-handler
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/geo-redundant-design#other-considerations
You can check Health of Azure Storage Account and initiate failover
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-disaster-recovery-guidance#track-outages
You can test failover scenario with Azure recommendations
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/simulate-primary-region-failure